# how to validate JSON schema of return type String| undefined using typescript

Tags: typescript, jsonschema

The two variants of my JSON response are:

```
{
  firstName: "abc",
  LastName: "xyz",
  Address: "abc123"
}
```

and

```
{
  firstName: undefined,
  LastName: undefined,
  Address: undefined
}
```

Even though defined JSON Schema as:

```
var ResponseSchema = {
  "firstName": {
    "type": [String,undefined],
  },
  "LastName": {
    "type": [String,undefined],
  },
  "Address": {
    "type": [String,undefined],
  },
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "LastName",
    "Address",
  ],
}
```

Response Object:

```
{
  firstName: undefined,
  LastName: undefined,
  Address: undefined
}
```

getting an error as:

requires property "firstName"
requires property "LastName"
requires property "Address"

using "jsonschema" Node package.

Comment: Your `jsonschema` tag looks inappropriate. The tag refers to *JSON schema*, as in *the schema for a JSON object*. However, you are probably referring to the *jsonschema* node package to validate a JSON object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First: Use proper type names in your schema (strings)**

You want to write a JSON schema. According to the definition, your `type` can either be a string or an array of strings. What you do is pass a TypeScript type definition in, not a string.

Try

```
  "firstName": {
    "type": ["string", "null"],
  },
  "LastName": {
    "type": ["string", "null"],
  },
  "Address": {
    "type": ["string","null"],
  },
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "LastName",
    "Address",
  ]
```

**Second: `undefined` is not a valid type for a JSON schema**

Having a property set to `undefined` is counted as that property not being set. I'd suggest you move to `null` for cases like that.

Comment: `undefined` isn't a type in JSON Schema because it's not a type in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *jsonschema*, but your definition and your required fields look some kind of conceptual error to me.

You define

```
"required": [
  "firstName", 
  "LastName", 
  "Address"
]
```

but set the type of every field to `String,undefined`. If you now set them to `undefined` the requirement is not met.

With other words: *jsonschema* seems to work, as it throws that error for your response:

```
{
  "firstname": undefined,
  "Lastname": undefined,
  "Address": undefined,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`null` is a valid type in JSON, and so is in [JSON Schema](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-01#section-4.2.1).

I don't know typescript, but here's a JSON Schema as an example.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "a"
  ]
}
```

And as an instance JSON, this would pass validation:

```
{
  "a": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `anyOf` to select between two schemas

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#id6

```json
"ResponseSchema": {
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "properties": {},
            "type": "object"
        },
        {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "firstName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "LastName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Address": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "firstName",
                "LastName",
                "Address"
            ],
            "type": "object"
        }
    ]
}
```

equivalent TypeScript type

```
type ResponseSchema = {
  firstName: string
  LastName: string
  Address: string
} | {}
```

Also `undefined` is not a type in JSON, so i have assumed the responses to be

either

```js
{
  firstName: "abc",
  LastName: "xyz",
  Address: "abc123"
}
```

or

```js
{}
```